# Moodle web-service Login problems

Tags: web-services, authentication, wsdl, moodle

I'm developing Moodle on my university. I got a web-service for users.

The question is :

1. How to make a Moodle Login using my own web-service?
2. Password format is different, my system use 6 digits numbering, and Moodle is using minimum 8 characters, at least 1 non-alphanumeric character(s)

Comment: You can disable moodle rules about passwords...

Answer (score 3):

You can use default webservice if you want then, but for that you need webservice token, `core_user_get_users_by_field` with this service you will get userid.

Then call `moodle_user_get_users_by_id` with username and password.

such as (1):

> `http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php??wstoken=35f5838a9dfsd41f8aca6394081e9faf7c52&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&moodlewsrestformat=json&field=username&values[0]=txtusername.txt`

and (2)

> `http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php??wstoken=35f5838a9dfsd41f8aca6394081e9faf7c52&wsfunction=moodle_user_get_users_by_id&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsusername=username&wspassword=password.txt&userids[0]=userid`

Hope this will help you, check this url in Google chrome postman plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a local Plugin in Moodle 2.9 that just sends Username & Password to that plugin and in return, the plugin should return True or False (You can modify according to your need).
Description:
Authenticate.php will GET two parameters and perform all authentication processes and return accordingly (For now I’m Printing the valid “$user” object if the Username & Passwords matches from “username” & “password” fields in mdl_users table). Moodle 2.9 verify a password against a hash using a timing attack resistant approach (http://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2009/57470001/57470001.pdf)
Plugin Location: moodle/location/auth_webservice/authenticate.php
Plugin Call: .../moodle/local/auth_webservice/authenticate.php?username=azzam&password=vwXyz.123

https://github.com/AzzamNisar/moodle-auth-plugin